# How to display the table with its rows which scrolls horizontally and vertically with first Column being fixed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

I want to have a table like structure which contains header row and data rows.
First column should be fixed,While Other Columns should be horizontally scrollable.Similarly data rows should also be vertically scrollable.How to achieve this in android.What sort of approach should i take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done with this help of code in below link
https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/08/android-scroll-table-fixed-header-column.html

```html
package com.Table;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TableMainLayout extends RelativeLayout {

 public final String TAG = "TableMainLayout.java";

 // set the header titles
 String headers[] = { "Header 1 \n multi-lines", "Header 2", "Header 3",
   "Header 4", "Header 5", "Header 6", "Header 7", "Header 8",
   "Header 9", "Header 10", "Header 11", "Header 12", "Header 13",
   "Header 14",

 };

 TableLayout tableA;
 TableLayout tableB;
 TableLayout tableC;
 TableLayout tableD;

 HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollViewB;
 HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollViewD;

 ScrollView scrollViewC;
 ScrollView scrollViewD;

 Context context;

 List<SampleObject> sampleObjects = this.sampleObjects();

 int headerCellsWidth[] = new int[headers.length];

 int screenWidthDp, screenHeightDp;

 public TableMainLayout(Context context) {

  super(context);

  this.context = context;

  // initialize the main components (TableLayouts, HorizontalScrollView,
  // ScrollView)
  this.initComponents();
  this.setComponentsId();
  this.setScrollViewAndHorizontalScrollViewTag();

  Configuration configuration = this.getResources().getConfiguration();
  screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp; // The current width of
              // the available
              // screen space, in
              // dp units,
              // corresponding to
              // screen width
              // resource
              // qualifier.
  screenHeightDp = configuration.screenHeightDp;

  // no need to assemble component A, since it is just a table
  this.horizontalScrollViewB.addView(this.tableB);

  this.scrollViewC.addView(this.tableC);

  this.scrollViewD.addView(this.horizontalScrollViewD);
  this.horizontalScrollViewD.addView(this.tableD);

  // add the components to be part of the main layout
  this.addComponentToMainLayout();

  // add some table rows
  this.addTableRowToTableA();
  this.addTableRowToTableB();

  this.resizeHeaderHeight();

  this.getTableRowHeaderCellWidth();

  this.generateTableC_AndTable_B();

  this.resizeBodyTableRowHeight();

 }

 // this is just the sample data
 List<SampleObject> sampleObjects() {

  List<SampleObject> sampleObjects = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();

  for (int x = 1; x <= 25; x++) {

   SampleObject sampleObject = new SampleObject("Col 1, Row " + x,
     "Col 2, Row " + x + " - multi-lines", "Col 3, Row " + x,
     "Col 4, Row " + x, "Col 5, Row " + x, "Col 6, Row " + x,
     "Col 7, Row " + x, "Col 8, Row " + x, "Col 9, Row " + x,
     "Col 10, Row " + x, "Col 11, Row " + x, "Col 12, Row " + x,
     "Col 13, Row " + x, "Col 14, Row " + x

   );

   sampleObjects.add(sampleObject);
  }

  return sampleObjects;

 }

 // initalized components
 private void initComponents() {

  this.tableA = new TableLayout(this.context);
  this.tableB = new TableLayout(this.context);
  this.tableC = new TableLayout(this.context);
  this.tableD = new TableLayout(this.context);

  this.horizontalScrollViewB = new MyHorizontalScrollView(this.context);
  this.horizontalScrollViewD = new MyHorizontalScrollView(this.context);

  this.scrollViewC = new MyScrollView(this.context);
  this.scrollViewD = new MyScrollView(this.context);

  this.tableA.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  this.horizontalScrollViewB.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

 }

 // set essential component IDs
 private void setComponentsId() {
  this.tableA.setId(1);
  this.horizontalScrollViewB.setId(2);
  this.scrollViewC.setId(3);
  this.scrollViewD.setId(4);
 }

 // set tags for some horizontal and vertical scroll view
 private void setScrollViewAndHorizontalScrollViewTag() {

  this.horizontalScrollViewB.setTag("horizontal scroll view b");
  this.horizontalScrollViewD.setTag("horizontal scroll view d");

  this.scrollViewC.setTag("scroll view c");
  this.scrollViewD.setTag("scroll view d");
 }

 // we add the components here in our TableMainLayout
 private void addComponentToMainLayout() {

  // RelativeLayout params were very useful here
  // the addRule method is the key to arrange the components properly
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams componentB_Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  componentB_Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, this.tableA.getId());

  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams componentC_Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  componentC_Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, this.tableA.getId());

  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams componentD_Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  componentD_Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
    this.scrollViewC.getId());
  componentD_Params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,
    this.horizontalScrollViewB.getId());

  // 'this' is a relative layout,
  // we extend this table layout as relative layout as seen during the
  // creation of this class
  this.addView(this.tableA);
  this.addView(this.horizontalScrollViewB, componentB_Params);
  this.addView(this.scrollViewC, componentC_Params);
  this.addView(this.scrollViewD, componentD_Params);

  tableA.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
  horizontalScrollViewB.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

 }

 private void addTableRowToTableA() {
  this.tableA.addView(this.componentATableRow());
 }

 private void addTableRowToTableB() {
  this.tableB.addView(this.componentBTableRow());
 }

 // generate table row of table A
 TableRow componentATableRow() {

  TableRow componentATableRow = new TableRow(this.context);
  TextView textView = this.headerTextView(this.headers[0]);
  componentATableRow.addView(textView);

  return componentATableRow;
 }

 // generate table row of table B
 TableRow componentBTableRow() {

  TableRow componentBTableRow = new TableRow(this.context);
  int headerFieldCount = this.headers.length;

  TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  params.setMargins(2, 0, 0, 0);

  for (int x = 0; x < (headerFieldCount - 1); x++) {
   TextView textView = this.headerTextView(this.headers[x + 1]);
   textView.setLayoutParams(params);
   componentBTableRow.addView(textView);
  }

  return componentBTableRow;
 }

 // generate table row of table C and table D
 private void generateTableC_AndTable_B() {

  // just seeing some header cell width
  for (int x = 0; x < this.headerCellsWidth.length; x++) {
   Log.v("TableMainLayout.java", this.headerCellsWidth[x] + "");
  }

  for (SampleObject sampleObject : this.sampleObjects) {

   TableRow tableRowForTableC = this.tableRowForTableC(sampleObject);
   TableRow taleRowForTableD = this.taleRowForTableD(sampleObject);

   tableRowForTableC.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
   taleRowForTableD.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

   this.tableC.addView(tableRowForTableC);
   this.tableD.addView(taleRowForTableD);

  }
 }

 // a TableRow for table C
 TableRow tableRowForTableC(SampleObject sampleObject) {

  TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
    this.headerCellsWidth[0], LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  params.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);

  TableRow tableRowForTableC = new TableRow(this.context);
  TextView textView = this.bodyTextView(sampleObject.header1);
  tableRowForTableC.addView(textView, params);

  return tableRowForTableC;
 }

 TableRow taleRowForTableD(SampleObject sampleObject) {

  TableRow taleRowForTableD = new TableRow(this.context);

  int loopCount = ((TableRow) this.tableB.getChildAt(0)).getChildCount();
  String info[] = { sampleObject.header2, sampleObject.header3,
    sampleObject.header4, sampleObject.header5,
    sampleObject.header6, sampleObject.header7,
    sampleObject.header8, sampleObject.header9,
    sampleObject.header10, sampleObject.header11,
    sampleObject.header12, sampleObject.header13,
    sampleObject.header14

  };

  for (int x = 0; x < loopCount; x++) {
   TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
     headerCellsWidth[x + 1], LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
   params.setMargins(2, 2, 0, 0);

   TextView textViewB = this.bodyTextView(info[x]);
   taleRowForTableD.addView(textViewB, params);
  }

  return taleRowForTableD;

 }

 // table cell standard TextView
 TextView bodyTextView(String label) {

  TextView bodyTextView = new TextView(this.context);
  bodyTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  bodyTextView.setText(label);
  bodyTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  bodyTextView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
  bodyTextView.setWidth(screenWidthDp / 3);
  return bodyTextView;
 }

 // header standard TextView
 TextView headerTextView(String label) {

  TextView headerTextView = new TextView(this.context);
  headerTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  headerTextView.setText(label);
  headerTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  headerTextView.setWidth(screenWidthDp / 3);
  headerTextView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
  return headerTextView;
 }

 // resizing TableRow height starts here
 void resizeHeaderHeight() {

  TableRow productNameHeaderTableRow = (TableRow) this.tableA
    .getChildAt(0);
  TableRow productInfoTableRow = (TableRow) this.tableB.getChildAt(0);

  int rowAHeight = this.viewHeight(productNameHeaderTableRow);
  int rowBHeight = this.viewHeight(productInfoTableRow);

  TableRow tableRow = rowAHeight < rowBHeight ? productNameHeaderTableRow
    : productInfoTableRow;
  int finalHeight = rowAHeight > rowBHeight ? rowAHeight : rowBHeight;

  this.matchLayoutHeight(tableRow, finalHeight);
 }

 void getTableRowHeaderCellWidth() {

  int tableAChildCount = ((TableRow) this.tableA.getChildAt(0))
    .getChildCount();
  int tableBChildCount = ((TableRow) this.tableB.getChildAt(0))
    .getChildCount();

  for (int x = 0; x < (tableAChildCount + tableBChildCount); x++) {

   if (x == 0) {
    this.headerCellsWidth[x] = this
      .viewWidth(((TableRow) this.tableA.getChildAt(0))
        .getChildAt(x));
   } else {
    this.headerCellsWidth[x] = this
      .viewWidth(((TableRow) this.tableB.getChildAt(0))
        .getChildAt(x - 1));
   }

  }
 }

 // resize body table row height
 void resizeBodyTableRowHeight() {

  int tableC_ChildCount = this.tableC.getChildCount();

  for (int x = 0; x < tableC_ChildCount; x++) {

   TableRow productNameHeaderTableRow = (TableRow) this.tableC
     .getChildAt(x);
   TableRow productInfoTableRow = (TableRow) this.tableD.getChildAt(x);

   int rowAHeight = this.viewHeight(productNameHeaderTableRow);
   int rowBHeight = this.viewHeight(productInfoTableRow);

   TableRow tableRow = rowAHeight < rowBHeight ? productNameHeaderTableRow
     : productInfoTableRow;
   int finalHeight = rowAHeight > rowBHeight ? rowAHeight : rowBHeight;

   this.matchLayoutHeight(tableRow, finalHeight);
  }

 }

 // match all height in a table row
 // to make a standard TableRow height
 private void matchLayoutHeight(TableRow tableRow, int height) {

  int tableRowChildCount = tableRow.getChildCount();

  // if a TableRow has only 1 child
  if (tableRow.getChildCount() == 1) {

   View view = tableRow.getChildAt(0);
   TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) view
     .getLayoutParams();
   params.height = height - (params.bottomMargin + params.topMargin);

   return;
  }

  // if a TableRow has more than 1 child
  for (int x = 0; x < tableRowChildCount; x++) {

   View view = tableRow.getChildAt(x);

   TableRow.LayoutParams params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) view
     .getLayoutParams();

   if (!isTheHeighestLayout(tableRow, x)) {
    params.height = height
      - (params.bottomMargin + params.topMargin);
    return;
   }
  }

 }

 // check if the view has the highest height in a TableRow
 private boolean isTheHeighestLayout(TableRow tableRow, int layoutPosition) {

  int tableRowChildCount = tableRow.getChildCount();
  int heighestViewPosition = -1;
  int viewHeight = 0;

  for (int x = 0; x < tableRowChildCount; x++) {
   View view = tableRow.getChildAt(x);
   int height = this.viewHeight(view);

   if (viewHeight < height) {
    heighestViewPosition = x;
    viewHeight = height;
   }
  }

  return heighestViewPosition == layoutPosition;
 }

 // read a view's height
 private int viewHeight(View view) {
  view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  return view.getMeasuredHeight();
 }

 // read a view's width
 private int viewWidth(View view) {
  // view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED,
  // View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
  return view.getMeasuredWidth();

 }

 // horizontal scroll view custom class
 class MyHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

  public MyHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
   super(context);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
   String tag = (String) this.getTag();

   if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("horizontal scroll view b")) {
    horizontalScrollViewD.scrollTo(l, 0);
   } else {
    horizontalScrollViewB.scrollTo(l, 0);
   }
  }

 }

 // scroll view custom class
 class MyScrollView extends ScrollView {

  public MyScrollView(Context context) {
   super(context);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

   String tag = (String) this.getTag();

   if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("scroll view c")) {
    scrollViewD.scrollTo(0, t);
   } else {
    scrollViewC.scrollTo(0, t);
   }
  }
 }

}
```

```html
package com.Table;

public class SampleObject {
 
 String header1;
 String header2;
 String header3;
 String header4;
 String header5;
 String header6;
 String header7;
 String header8;
 String header9;
 String header10;
 String header11;
 String header12;
 String header13;
 String header14;
 
 
 
 public SampleObject(String header1, String header2, String header3,
   String header4, String header5, String header6,
   String header7, String header8, String header9,String header10, String header11, String header12,String header13, String header14){
  
  this.header1 = header1;
  this.header2 = header2;
  this.header3 = header3;
  this.header4 = header4;
  this.header5 = header5;
  this.header6 = header6;
  this.header7 = header7;
  this.header8 = header8;
  this.header9 = header9;
  this.header10 = header10;
  this.header11= header11;
  this.header12 = header12;
  this.header13= header13;
  this.header14 = header14;
  
  
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, could you include the relevant parts of your link in your answer please? That way, if the link goes dead/is blocked by firewall, etc., your answer is still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two tables ,one for the column that will be fixed and other table containing the rest of the data which could be scrollable using scollview tag .

Comment: when scrolling horizontalscrollable table vertically,I need to scroll the fixed table element vertically also.How to do this

Comment: im sorry , but could explain clearly what do you want in the last cooment??

Comment: When I am scrolling table which has scrollview tag,Table which is fixed should also be getting scrolled along with vertically.I am making clear to you